# Yii2 compare and highlight difference between two strings or text in gridview

Tags: string, yii2, highlight, difference

Is there a way to make it work?
I was looking for a solution but found nothing much relevant. It would be nice if StringHelper would have a such a method!
There has to be a text diff function somewhere somehow in yii2 because in gii there is also a highlight of differences, isn't it?
DiffRendererHtmlInline? What is this? It's from gii. Can we make use of it somehow?

https://github.com/pdjshog/yii2/blob/master/framework/gii/components/Pear/Text/Diff.php

It should be there but I can't find it in my Yii.
In fact there are others in yii framework:

- phpspec/php-diff/lib/Diff.php

Looks quite good. Can we use it somehow?

Comment: try adding some more content and description for your question as it would fall into low quality posts in review , due to less content , try adding an example code for what you results you desire

Comment: Well if you want to compare 2 strings say `Hello, This is the original text.` and `This is the original text, with some deletion and addition.`  which gives you something like in this [image](https://imgur.com/a/heQCTqu) , i might be able to hep you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can. It's not perfect but I can change it a little bit to suit my needs.

https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-diff/blob/master/example/example.php

So it's already there in yii, you don't have to install anything.

I've added the following to index.php:

```
require_once \Yii::$app->basePath . '/vendor/phpspec/php-diff/lib/Diff.php';
require_once \Yii::$app->basePath . '/vendor/phpspec/php-diff/lib/Diff/Renderer/Html/InlineMy.php';
```

Well the only problem is that none of the outputs are really perfect for me: the text renders are too few, the html renders are complete tables, and in a gridview it's not really nice, so I have made a copy of Inline.php as InlineMy.php and deleted all the stuff I don't need:

```
public function render() {
    $changes = parent::render();
    $html = '';
    if (empty($changes)) {
        return $html;
    }

    foreach ($changes as $i => $blocks) {
        foreach ($blocks as $change) {
            if ($change['tag'] == 'replace') {
                foreach ($change['base']['lines'] as $no => $line) {
                    $html .= '<span style="white-space: nowrap">' . $line . '</span><br>';
                }

                foreach ($change['changed']['lines'] as $no => $line) {
                    $html .= '<span style="white-space: nowrap">' . $line . '</span>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
```

furthermore, I have changed this in parent (Array.php):

```
<del> ==> <del style="background-color: red">
<ins> ==> <ins style="background-color: green">
```

I'm using at the moment SqlDataProvider, so my gridview looks a little bit different than usual (ActiveDataProvider):

```
[
    'attribute' => 'diff',
    'value' => function ($row) {
        $diff = new Diff(explode("\n", $row["name"]), explode("\n", $row["name2"]));
        $renderer = new Diff_Renderer_Html_Inline;
        return $diff->render($renderer);
    },
    'format' => 'html',
],
```

Output:

> some<strike>thing</strike> <== red
>
> some**what** <== that's actually underlined and green, not bold

I'm sure one can make it more elegant but in a quick and dirty way it's fine for me at the moment because I don't want to build it furthermore.